# Exclude null results in PrincipalSearcher QueryFilter for Active Directory in C#

Tags: c#, active-directory

Trying to search Active Directory for non null descriptions on users (meaning they have a job title) as seen in line 4 below but am getting an error that I can not use the exclusion !

Suggestions for another approach?

```
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
UserPrincipal qbeUser = new UserPrincipal(ctx);
PrincipalSearcher srch = new PrincipalSearcher(qbeUser);
var example = new UserPrincipal(ctx) { Description != null };
```

Comment: What error message are you getting?

Answer (score 4):

I would try something like this:

```
using (PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
{
    UserPrincipal qbeUser = new UserPrincipal(ctx);
    qbeUser.Description = "*";   // something, anything - just not empty/NULL

    PrincipalSearcher srch = new PrincipalSearcher(qbeUser);
     ......
}
```

Does that work for you? Basically, just define the property on the `qbeUser` and using the `*` as a wildcard says you want users which have something in the `Description` property - something, anything - just not nothing.